# Julia dies on creation of contour plot

Tags: plot, julia

I want to make a contour plot of the loss space for a rather simple regression. Whenever I go to plot the space my session dies. Is there something that I'm doing wrong or do I need to trouble shoot installation? (just installed a couple days ago but haven't used Julia before)

```
using Plots, DataFrames, StatsPlots, Statistics, LinearAlgebra

f(t) = t.^2
c(θ₁, θ₂) = sum(f(t)-θ₁*t-θ₂*t.^2)

t = LinRange(0,1,20) |> collect
θ₁ = LinRange(-3,2,100) |> collect
θ₂ = LinRange(-1,3.5,100)|> collect

X = [t t.^2]
θ = [θ₁ θ₂]

yhats = X * transpose(θ)
ytrue = t.^2

e = yhats .- ytrue
tse = sum(e.^2, dims=1)

contour(θ[:,1],θ[:,2], tse)
```

Comment: Your example errors out for me: `Arrays have incorrect length or dimension`, but doesn't end the session, so it seems to be an issue with your installation. As an aside, note that you don't have to be `using Plots, StatsPlots`, as `StatsPlots` reexports `Plots`. And I believe `countour` is in standard `Plots` so you could forgo `StatsPlots` here.

Comment: Also, don't use `collect`. You virtually never need to use `collect`, since ranges behave like arrays (in fact they *are* arrays.) Just remove the `|> collect` parts, and forget you ever heard about `collect` (until something actually stops working.)

Comment: I removed Julia and the folders, reinstalled it, only installed Plots, and still got the same issue... I’m not sure why there should be an error because they’re all 100x1 vectors... Could I get a little more help either troubleshooting or figuring out what’s going wrong?

Comment: It looks like the third argument to `contour` needs to be either a bivariate function or a matrix. Your code appears to supply a vector for the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do

```
using Plots
f(t) = t^2
y(θ₁, θ₂, t) = θ₁ * t + θ₂ * t^2
ts = LinRange(0, 1, 20)
e(θ₁, θ₂) = sum(abs2, f(t) - y(θ₁, θ₂, t) for t in ts)
θ₁ = LinRange(-3, 2, 100)
θ₂ = LinRange(-1, 3.5, 100)
contourf(θ₁, θ₂, e)
```

which gives

[image]